# DOS Command FindStr

Tags: command, dos, findstr

I have a need to use the DOS command FINDSTR to search in all our source code files mixed with other types of files such as PDF, exe, dll, etc.

I do not need to search those binary files. Is there a way to exclude binary files?

My command looks like

```
findstr /r /n /o /s /g:c:\projects\vsssearch\muafinddata.txt /d:c:/projects/axl *.axl > output.txt
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

John

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do yo try /p? Help says: "/P Skip files with non-printable characters."

Comment: Thanks. That helped in skipping those binary files.